# statistics z score

Tags: normal-distribution, average, percentile

I'm curious what the phrase "on average" means. Here is an example:

> On average, 30% were further than ___ kilometers away when they had their accident.

Is $30\%$ a $z$-score or is it a mean? 
Transport Canada was investigating accident records to find out how far from their residence people were to when they got into a traffic accident. They took the population of accident records from Ontario and measured the distance the drivers were from home when they had their accident in kilometers (km). The distribution of 
distances was normally shaped, with $µ = 30$ kilometers and $σ = 8.0$ kilometers.

Comment: Nice job supplying the context for your Question.  The phrase "on average" has quite a range of meanings depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

**Calculation by using the z-score**

The equation is $P(X > x)=0.3$

We know, that $P(X > x)=1-P(X \leq x)$

Thus the equation with the standard normal distribution is:

$1-\Phi \left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.3$, with $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$

Z is standard normal distributed: Z $\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

$1-\Phi \left( \frac{x-30}{8}\right)=0.3 \quad | -1$

$-\Phi \left( \frac{x-30}{8}\right)=-0.7 \quad | \cdot (-1)$

$\Phi \left( \frac{x-30}{8}\right)=0.7 \quad$

Taking the inverse function.

$ \frac{x-30}{8}=\Phi^{-1}(0.7) \quad$

Now you have to find the corresponding z-score for $p=0.7$. Then solve the equation for x.

Comment: Sorry --- a momentary mental glitch.  But you still haven't said anything about what "on average" means.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I just wanted to point out the meaning of the z-score in this exercise. It seemed to me, that is was unclear to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "on average" means in this context, and I have a Ph.D. in statistics.  The sentence is one that looks perfectly sensible until you think about what it says.  Probably what was intended was "$30\%$ of the drivers were more than how many kilometers from home?".  How an "average" gets involved I don't know.

**PS:** One could say that $0.3$ is an average of $0$s and $1$s.  Assign to each accident a $1$ or a $0$ according as it was or was not in excess of the stated distance from home.  But the statement that $30\%$ is the proportion of the population involved is something that involves only one number: $30\%$, not a average of various percentages.

Comment: I got another question that is related to this, can you please tell me if i am correct.

If a random sample 5000 were taken from this dataset, how many of these individuals would you expect were less than 35 kilometers away when they got into an accident? I am asking about the number of individuals from a sample of 5000 that you would be expect to have had their accident when they were less than 35 kilometers  away from their home.

would the 5000 be part of the standard error equation meaning 8/square root of 5000 and then apply that to the z = x - m/ standard error. seems pretty big to me

Comment: Look at $z=(35-30)/(8/\sqrt{5000})$.  Find $\Phi(z)$, and that's it.  This part makes sense even if it is not known that the population is normally distributed, but it assumes the population mean is known to be $30$ kilometers and the population standard deviation is known to be $8$ kilometers. ${}\qquad{}$